# showing a message if there is no div child matched with text box text

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am looking to show a message if a div have no child element after my function done. iam using a function here for search option which is for showing the div child element which have match with the search box text. 1. my requrement is i need to show a message if there is no matching with search box text and div child element.
i try some code that is here

```
$('#searchtool').click(function(){

   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis == ""){
        $('.rightSidIcons> div').show();
    } else {
        $('.rightSidIcons> div').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();


         });

    }
     if($(".rightSidIcons").children().length == 0){
                $(".rightSidIcons").text("this item not found")
          }
      });



 <div class="searchBox  downbox"><input id="searchtool" name="" type="text" class="searchboxCss">
                </div>
<div class="rightSidIcons">
<div>manu</div>
<div>anu</div>
<div>sanu</div>
<div>janu</div>
<div>meenu</div>

<div>shinu</div>
<div>mansey</div>
<div>anusree</div>

</div>
```

Comment: share html part!!

Comment: @BhumiShah i add the htmlpart

Comment: @manup it's just a typing mistake... "rightSidIcons" and "rightSidIcon" !!!

Comment: no i correct that but still its not working

Comment: instead of `click` event use `change`

Comment: actually the problem is  $(".rightSidIcons").children().length === 0 . here i am  looking to count the child element length. instead of this how i count the child elements have property display :block.

Comment: Try with `$(".rightSidIcons").children().length < 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$(".rightSidIcons > div:visible").length === 0` instead of `$(".rightSidIcons").children().length === 0`

`:visible` will give you only those data are visible in the document

And you also need to use `keyup` event instead of `click` event.

[**FIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cjhz7gvr/)

Comment: instead of alert i want to print text in rightsideicons div .

Comment: second time after print the text in div it is not working

Comment: yes it will not working as it will remove your `.rightSidIcons > div` data. Use another div to print text (i.e if search result has data hide the new div and when no data show the new div).

Comment: `$('.rightSidIcons').text("not found")` use this code. you may get.

Comment: @MathankumarK, it won't work also. It will remove whole data under `rightSidIcons` div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a marker class 'active' to all the divs that need to be displayed and check for any div with this class'

```
 $('#searchtool').on('keyup',function(){

   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis == ""){
        $('.rightSidIcons > div').show();
    } else {
        $('.rightSidIcons > div').removeClass('active');
        $('.rightSidIcons> div').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if( (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0))
            {
              $(this).addClass('active');
              $(this).show();
            }
            else
            {
              $(this).hide();
            }});    
    }
     if($(".rightSidIcons > div.active").length === 0){
              alert("dd")
          }
      });
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fs5x9cqz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the js code to search and message display:

```
$('#searchtool').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp('^' + value, 'i');
    var flag = 0;
    var matchtxt = 0;
    $('.rightSidIcons > div').each(function() { 
        var isMatch = exp.test($(this).text());
        if(isMatch == false)
            matchtxt++;
        $(this).toggle(isMatch);
        flag++;
    });
    if(matchtxt == flag){
        console.log(matchtxt);console.log(flag);
        alert('No matching text');
    }
})
```